# What are fanners?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, poetry

In the Rudyard Kipling poem [The Bee-Boy's Song](http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poems_beeboy.htm) there is a section that goes:

> Tell 'em coming in an' out,
>   Where the Fanners fan,

What are these fanners that the bees are so curious to know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kipling's animal fable "The Mother Hive" (1908) includes these passages:

> The old Queen cried the Swarming Cry, which to a bee of good blood should be what the trumpet was to Job’s war-horse. In spite of her immense age (three, years), it rang between the canon-like frames as a pibroch rings in a mountain pass; the **fanners** changed their note, and repeated it up in every gallery; and the broad-winged drones, burly and eager, ended it on one nerve-thrilling outbreak of bugles: “*La Reine le veult!* Swarm! Swar-rm! Swar-r-rm!”

> Sacharissa had run to what was left of the fertile brood-comb. “Down and out!” she called across the brown breadth of it. “Nurses, guards, **fanners**, sweepers—out! Never mind the babies. They’re better dead.—Out, before the Light and the Hot Smoke!”

It's clear from this story that Kipling understood *fanners* to be a caste of worker bees.

Answer (score 7):

My guess would be that this is about [bees fanning their wings at the hive entrance](http://www.beekeeping.isgood.ca/behaviour/bees-fanning-their-wings-at-the-entrance) to cool parts of the hive. The place where the bees come in and out of the hive is exactly where they do this.

Comment: Given Kipling's association with India, he may have also been thinking of human punkah_wallahs, who because of their work often overheard private conversations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punkah_wallah. For the background context to the whole poem, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telling_the_bees

Answer (score 1):

OED *fanner, n* gives definition 1.a. obs.

> One who winnows [separates wheat from chaff using air] grain with a fan.

This seems more relevant than the other definition "one who fans". Winnowing does not seem particularly relevant to the poem as a whole, but the agrarian context does fit a poem about bees.